# Hexadecimal representation taking more space than it should

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, hex, byte

I have Strings, which are always hexadecimal, like "FF", "BB", "AA" etc.
I did a small experiment with encoding stuff, and it looks like `hexadecimal` is taking double the number of bytes than these things in String representation.

My code's like this:

```
        String hex ="FF";

        byte[] b = hex.getBytes();
        String enc = base16().encode(hex.getBytes());
        byte[] c = enc.getBytes();
```

I'm using Guava utils to do the encoding stuff.

It appears as `hex` taking two bytes, so `b` is of length 2.
Then I encode it to hexadecimal. "FF" is 255 in decimal, so it needs to take `1 byte`. But `enc` is now 4 bytes and is equal to `"4646"`.

Next, `c` is 4 bytes.

I don't understand the point where `enc` is getting generated. I want `c` to take 1 byte. Can someone throw some light?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getBytes()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) doesn't do what you think it does.  It doesn't parse it as a hexadecimal number; it gives the character encodings.  The character `F` is number `70`, so `hex.getBytes()` gets you a two-byte array of `'F', 'F'`, or `70, 70`.

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

To parse it as a hexadecimal number, you can use `Integer.parseInt` with a radix of 16.

```
byte[] c = { (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex, 16) };
```

`Integer.parseInt` is used instead of `Byte.parseByte` because `FF` is too large for a signed byte.

Output:

```
[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer.parseInt(hex,16)` to convert the hex String to an int. Then you can convert it to bytes.

When you call `hex.getBytes()`, you get the byte representation of the two `F` characters in the default encoding. That usually requires at least one byte per character, and it doesn't treat your `"FF"` String as a hexadeciaml number.